# In Google Spreadsheets how do I put in a formula in after a transpose?

Tags: google-sheets

In my spreadsheet the transpose formula fills in a deliberately variable number of column cells, how do I fill in a cell after a transpose formula?

Answer (score 1):

### There are three ways to resolve this phenomenon

*First*
Use an explicit range in your formula:
`=TRANSPOSE(sheet2!A1:A12)`

*Second*
Filter out empty cells:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2Sheet2!A2:A<>"")))`

*Third*
Remove all "physical" rows beyond A12 in sheet 2. Then your original formula will work as well

### Afterwards, use this script to add additional information

```
// get active spreadsheet (GLOBAL)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  // create menu
  var menu = [{name: "add additional data via script", 
                 functionName: "addData"},
    {name: "add additional data via formula", 
                 functionName: "addDataFormula"}];

  // add to menu
  ss.addMenu("Add Info", menu); 
}

function addData() {
  // get active sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // array with header names
  var aHeader = ss.getSheetByName("Extra").getDataRange().getValues();

  // get last filled column header and add one
  var emptyCol = sh.getLastColumn()+1;  

  // get range and set values
  var range = sh.getRange(1, parseInt(emptyCol), 1, aHeader.length)
    .setValues([aHeader]);
}

function addDataFormula() {
  // get active sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // array with header names
  var aHeader = ss.getSheetByName("Extra").getDataRange().getValues();

  // get last filled column header and add one
  var emptyCol = sh.getLastColumn()+1;  

  // get range and set values
  var formula = '=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Extra!A:A,Extra!A:A<>"")))';
  var range = sh.getRange(1, parseInt(emptyCol), 1, aHeader.length)
    .setFormula(formula );
}
```

The script adds an item to the menu structure called "Add Info". Choosing one of the items, will result in the addition of the extra information.
Add the script like this: tools, script editor.  Make sure to de-bug (press bug) the code.

See example file I've prepared: [example file](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdDdvYnVBREFMdXZaZnhtVURQbG1Mc1E&usp=sharing)

Comment: thanks Jacob, so after the transpose formula has filled out the columns, where do I put any subsequent formulas for columns I'd like adjacent to the transpose column? Hope that makes sense.